# Filter Embedded Json element from a Collection using AngularJS HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, angular-filters

I'm having a JSON Collection, I wish to dispay Email ID which is marked as **`IsPreffered = TRUE`** using AngularJS HTML without .
user.Name

My JSON Collection :

```
{ "user" : [
    {
        "Name" : "B. Balamanigandan",
        "Email": [
            {
                "Id": "bala@gmail.com",
                "IsPreffered": true
            },
            {
                "Id": "mani@gmail.com",
                "IsPreffered": false
            }
    ]}
]};
```

HTML Source Code:

```
<div>
    <h3>Employee Details:</h3>
    <span> {{collection.user.Name}} </span>
    <span> {{collection.user.Email.Id}} </span>
</div>
```

The Collection **`user`** contains only one **document**. So, I didn't use ng-repeat. **`user` is a Collection not a Document**. One more check I need. If more than one email has `IsPreferred == true', then I have the take the last one. Kindly assist me.

Kindly filter the condition using HTML Level not in JavaScript Level. Kindly assist me.

Comment: Where is your ngRepeat?

Comment: @dfsq The Collection **user** contains only one document. So, I didn't use ng-repeat. **user** is a Collection not a Document. Kindly assist me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of this:

```
<div>
    <h3>Employee Details:</h3>
    <span> {{collection.user.Name}} </span>
    <span> {{collection.user.Email.Id}} </span>
</div>
```

you will have to do this:

```
<div>
    <h3>Employee Details:</h3>
    <span> {{collection.user[0].Name}} </span>

    <span ng-repeat="email in collection.user[0].email| filter: {IsPreffered : 'true'}"> {{email.Id}} </span>
</div>
```

You have to use array syntax, because although there is only 1 user object, it is structured in the json as an array ( note the [ ] , same for Email).

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5593/

UPDATE: For showing only the last email which is true, use ng-if:

```
<span ng-repeat="email in collection.user[0].Email| filter: {IsPreffered : true} " ng-if="$last"> {{email.Id}}</span>
```

Here is the updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5594/

Comment: Thanks but one more check I need. If more than one email has **`IsPreferred == true'**, then I have the take the last one. Kindly assist me please.

Comment: Please update your question details, to mention this.

Comment: I need one more solution from you. I posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37905191/map-two-collections-inner-join-using-angularjs-html Kindly assist me.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use `ngRepeat` on the user Emails array with a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) to get only those Emails where `"IsPreffered": true`. The filter compares each object in the Emails array with the filter object (`filterEmail`). This filter object is defined in the controller - this way you will be able to change by demand or even set it dynamically.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.collection = {
    "user": {
      "Name": "B. Balamanigandan",
      "Email": [{
        "Id": "bala@gmail.com",
        "IsPreffered": true
      }, {
        "Id": "mani@gmail.com",
        "IsPreffered": false
      }]
    }
  };

  $scope.filterEmail = {
    "IsPreffered": true
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div>
    <h3>Employee Details:</h3>
    <span> {{collection.user.Name}} </span>
    <span ng-repeat="email in collection.user.Email | filter : filterEmail "> 
      {{email.Id}} 
    </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

NOTE: To my understanding it doesn't make much sense to have `user` as an array inside an object (in my example I removed the inner array). If you insist on keeping this data-schema, you will need to change every reference of `collection.user` to `collection.user[0]`.