# Map two json arrays using filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-filter

I'm developing a forum using AngularJS and interfacing MySQL with a WS API. My idea is when I user replies I should get the reply and his/her name.

[image: App View]

This is my DB MER

[image: MER DB Model]

As you can see,

- **One tema**(topic) can have **many respuesta**(replies).
- **One persona**(users) can have **many respuesta**(replies) and also **many tema**(topics).

Now, In forum controller, I'm getting with `$http` two responses:

- `url2` -> get replies of the topic filtering with **id**(from `$routeParams`) = **id_tema**(on db)
- `url3` -> get users in general, and should be filtered in forum.html, in order to get the name of the user which is repliying the topic.

forum-controller.js

```
angular.module('rhoAppApp')
  .controller('temaCtrl', function ($routeParams, $scope, $http) {


    var id = $routeParams.id;

    var url = 'http://server/api.php/tema?filter=id,eq,' + id;

                 $http.get(url).then(function (response) {

                    $scope.titulo = response.data.tema.records[0][1];
                    $scope.texto = response.data.tema.records[0][2];

                })

    var url2 = 'http://server/api.php/respuesta?filter=id_tema,eq,' + id;

                 $http.get(url2).then(function (response) {

                    $scope.respuestas = response.data.respuesta.records;

                })

    var url3 = 'http://server/api.php/persona'

                 $http.get(url3).then(function (response) {

                    $scope.personas = response.data.persona.records;

                })    

  });
```

Now, I'm triying to map `url2` with `url3` using filters.

`persona[0]` (user id) should be equal to `respuesta[3]`, in order two get user name `persona[3]`.

So I followed the next question [Map two Collections (Inner Join)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37905191/map-two-collections-inner-join-using-angularjs-html) and I did something similar in the HTML:

```
<table class="table">
            <tbody> 
                <tr><th>{{titulo}}</a></th></tr>
                <tr><td>{{texto}}</td></tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="respuesta in respuestas | orderBy : 'respuesta[0]'" id="{{respuesta[0]}} " ><td>
                Por  <span ng-repeat="persona in personas | filter:{persona[0]:respuesta[3]}"> {{persona[3]}} </span>, el {{respuesta[2] | badDateToISO | date:'shortDate'}} a las {{respuesta[2] | badDateToISO | date: "HH:mm"}} Hrs.
                <br>
                <br>
                {{respuesta[1]}}
                </td></tr>
                <tr><td>
                <form >
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" required></textarea>
                <br>
                <button type="button" class="width-35 center-block btn btn-sm btn-primary" ng-click="urlbtn()"> 
                Responder
                </button>
                </form>
                </td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

My problem is with this expression `filter:{persona[0]:respuesta[3]}`, it seems to be that AngularJS doesn't accept 2 arrays expression at the same filter. Also, I have used `'persona[0]:respuesta[3]'`, but didn't work.

I got this error with this `filter:{persona[0]:respuesta[3]}`

```
angular.js:14110 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '[' is unexpected, expecting [}] at column 27 of the expression [personas | filter:{persona[0]:respuesta[3]}] starting at [[0]:respuesta[3]}].
```

the other, I didn't get errors, but also I didn't get the user name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, I found this [map array to another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30044067/angularjs-map-array-to-another-array)

And I replace `filter` for `ng-if`

```
 <span ng-repeat="persona in personas" ng-if="respuesta[3] === persona[0]" > {{persona[3]}} {{persona[4]}} {{persona[5]}}</span>
```